# Serialize two querysets with DjangoRestFramework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to serialize more than one queryset, but I noticed that only one of them becomes serialized. This is the approach I'm currently trying.

```
class GetDetails(APIView):   
    def get(self, request):

        todays_date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
       #Get results according to specified criteria
        queryset = People.objects.filter(date = todays_date, assigned_to = 1)
       #Check if any querysets are available
        if queryset:
       #Iterate through each queryset, serialize and return a response
            for person in queryset:
                serializer=ASerializer(person)

            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response({'TODO':'TODO'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the way you are performing queryset is not right, you are iterating over queryset with person variable and you are not using person variable at all.

And for the question, use `many=True` attribute of serializer. It will create a list of serialized items for you.

like this:

```
class GetDetails(APIView):   
    def get(self, request):
        todays_date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        queryset = People.objects.filter(date = todays_date, assigned_to = 1)
        return Response(ASerializer(many=True).to_representation(queryset))
```

Comment: That was my mistake when I added the question. I've edited it in case anyone else finds this useful. Thanks for your help, It's just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your code should be like this:

```
    def get(self, request):
        todays_date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        queryset = People.objects.filter(date = todays_date, assigned_to = 1)
        if queryset.exists():  # Lazy check if entry Exists.
            serializer=ASerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response({'TODO':'TODO'})
```